# Elegant way to process collection_select in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently somewhat stuck figuring out an elegant solution to my following 
problem:

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reg_template, :class_name => "EmailTemplate"
  [...]
end

class EmailTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  [...]
end
```

And a view that contains:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:reg_template_id, EmailTemplate.all, :id, :name) %>
```

What is the recommended way of processing this form field in an action 
controller?

Having a 1:1 relationship between Event and EmailTemplate means that Rails 
does not generate a reg_template_id and reg_template_id= method (as it would 
do for a 1:n relationship), so attempts to read or assign this field will fail 
with

```
unknown attribute: reg_template_id
```

when attempting to call

```
Event.update_attributes
```

Using

```
<%= f.collection_select(:reg_template, EmailTemplate.all, :id, :name) %>
```

instead also does not help much as it will fail with:

```
EmailTemplate(#70070455907700) expected, got String(#70070510199800)
```

I guess I must be missing something terribly obvious as I think is is rather 
common to update a model instance with a reference to another object through a 
collection_select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the column `reg_template_id` in the `events` table, then the following code should work:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:reg_template_id, EmailTemplate.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: The foreign key in the events table is named `reg_template_id`, but unfortunately using it yields the `unknown attribute: reg_template_id` error I mentioned above. Would changing its name to `email_template_id` change anything about the situation?

Comment: The foreign key `reg_template_id` should work. What happens when you create an instance of Event object and access `reg_template_id`? i.e. `Event.new.reg_template_id`

Comment: Did you run all migrations yet?

Comment: Well, seems I had manually added the column with the wrong name (while it was correctly named in the migration). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Came here looking how to do this, followed the Q&A, and had the same problem. Turned out I ALSO added the migration with the wrong name (plural, instead of singular). So thanks for confessing your error - saved me quite some time !